# difference in sharepoint 2010 apps and 2013 apps

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I am new to SharePoint and want to understand following concept about SharePoint apps:

I want to if apps are introduced in SharePoint 2013 or they were also existing in SharePoint 2010?

If they were present in SharePoint 2010 then what is the difference between SharePoint 2010 apps and SharePoint 2013 apps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Apps was introduced in SharePoint Server 2013 and is based on a new concept usually depending on client side code, especially in Office 365. But on premise you can still use .net framework to produce apps for SharePoint Server.

An app is supposed to work in an isolated container who shouldn't have the potential or risk to break a SharePoint Page, which a web part can. The aim from Microsoft is to secure SharePoint from potentially malicious code, making SharePoint unresponsive.

The intention is also for the App to consume REST APIs for everything it does, but it doesn't have to be that way. Read more on...

[Overview of apps for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[YouTube: SharePoint Apps (the initial scare)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xy6EBzOcslU)

Answer (score 1):

**READ [Overview of apps for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179930%28v=office.15%29.aspx)**

Sharepoint Apps are completly new in Sharepoint 2013.

In SharePoint 2010 you can not deploy Sharepoint App because the enviroment of SharePoint 2010 do not support this tecnology.

For SharePoint Apps exists an different deployment methodology.

The following figure shows the conceptual architecture for building apps for SharePoint.

[image]

Multiple options for hosting
[image]

[How to: Publish an app for SharePoint by using Visual Studio.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220044.aspx)

[How to: Submit apps for SharePoint to the Office Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220033.aspx)